# How to prevent the system space from running out while running the code

Tags: python, memory, spyder

I have a very long python code to run and when I ran it in the morning, my system ran out of memory space. I believe this is because of the large list which keeps growing with each iteration. Is there any way I can compile this without losing all the memory space?
If I paste the code into a hard disk, and if I run it from there, will that solve the issue?
I am using spyder.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the space your code is using, is stack and heap, if you run the code keeping list in variables(or memmory), this memmory is your ram not your hard disk. Therefore running it from a disk won't solve this problem. you can think about storing the list(which you think is consuming memmory) in a database or physical file(text file). However you might want to check if this list is really the cause, before attempting to solve it.

Comment: In any case, please show the code you're running too.

Answer (score 0):

No, saving the program elsewhere from your IDE won't help with that. It's possible running it with the regular Python interpreter instead of something Spyder maybe embeds may help a bit.

You'll need to either (from easiest to hardest):

- enable swap memory on your machine (which will make your program slow to run if it needs to use that swap memory)
- purchase and install more memory into your machine
- run your program on e.g. a cloud machine with more memory
- make your program use less memory with a more efficient algorithm (e.g. better data structures, or storing parts of the calculation on the disk).

Comment: Enabling swap will not necessarily make a program run slower **unless** the swap space is actually utilised

Comment: @DarkKnight That's true (edited into the answer), but also a little beside the point if OP is getting a MemoryError anyway. The options are to crash (without swap) or be slow (with swap).